# How to convert data row to column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to make data row to a column in SQL Server, and this case I use pivot but the result is null. This is data before I use pivot

[image]

and after use pivot this is the result :

[image]

This is my query :

```
SELECT 
    *  
FROM   
    (SELECT 
         A.asset, 
         A.inspection_title, 
         A.question, A.answer, 
         (LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.assign_date, 101), 6) 
              + RIGHT(Year(a.assign_date), 2)) AS [datee] 
     FROM   
         vw_amtiss_inspection_answers A 
     JOIN 
         vw_asset_r B ON a.asset = b.asset_code 
     WHERE  
         A.inspection_code LIKE '%-DC-%' 
         AND b.equip_grp_id = 'HD7857' 
         AND a.asset = 'DT7014' 
         AND A.assign_date IN (SELECT TOP 5 A.assign_date 
                               FROM vw_amtiss_inspection_answers A 
                               JOIN vw_asset_r B ON a.asset = b.asset_code 
                               WHERE A.inspection_code LIKE '%-DC-%' 
                                 AND b.equip_grp_id = 'HD7857' 
                                 AND a.asset = 'DT7014' 
                               GROUP BY a.assign_date 
                               ORDER  BY a.assign_date DESC) 
    GROUP BY 
        a.asset, a.inspection_title, 
        a.question, a.answer, 
        b.equip_grp_id, a.assign_date) C 
PIVOT 
    (MIN(answer) 
        FOR datee IN (jawaban_1, jawaban_2, jawaban_3, 
                      jawaban_4, jawaban_5)) AS p
```

Please help me to solve this case.. Thanks

Comment: Could you have a `jawaban_6`, `_7`, ... `_99`, or is `_5` the max? Also, please don't post data as an image, post it as `text`, or (even better) as DDL (`CREATE`) and DML (`INSERT`) statements.

Comment: @Larnu no just five..sorry for image

Comment: OK, and what should results are you expecting? obviously the second image isn't what you're after (as otherwise you wouldn't be posting a question).

Comment: @Larnu same with second image but i want in coloumn jawaban_1 is OK not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your data is still an image I've not transcribed this properly. This, however, should be enough to get you to the answer you want:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT 'DT7014' AS Col1,
           'Daily Check' As Col2,
           'Water Level' AS Question,
           'Ok' AS Answer,
           CONVERT(date,'20190206') AS [Date]
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'DT7014' AS Col1,
           'Daily Check' As Col2,
           'Water Level' AS Question,
           NULL AS Answer,
           '20190215' AS [Date]),
CTE AS(
    SELECT VTE.Col1,
           VTE.Col2,
           VTE.Question,
           VTE.Answer,
           VTE.[Date],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1, VTE.Col2, VTE.Question ORDER BY [Date]) AS RN
    FROM VTE)
SELECT C.Col1,
       C.Col2,
       C.Question,
       MAX(CASE C.RN WHEN 1 THEN Answer END) AS J1,
       MAX(CASE C.RN WHEN 2 THEN Answer END) AS J2
FROM CTE C
GROUP BY C.Col1,
         C.Col2,
         C.Question;
```

There is a **big** caveat though. Your image **strongly implies** that your column `datee` isn't the datatype `date`, but the datatype `varchar`. The above won't work as expected if so. For example, with dates the statement `'20181219' < '20190104'` is true, however, with your data the statement `'12/19/18' < '04/01/19'` is false (`'1' > '0'` and so the `varchar` **representation** of the date *19 December 2018* is **after** the `varchar` representation of the date *04 January 2019*). The way to fix this is to fix your datatype in your table. `varchar` is *not* a "one size fits all datatype".